# Jupyter Notebook stuck in loading loop in VSCode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I somehow recently am not able to load my notebooks anymore in VSCode. I do not know how to solve this infinite loading problem.

Below a screenshot:

[image]

And another one:

[image]

So far Google was not able to help. Hope someone here can.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try updating VS Code? sometimes extension versions get updated to match latest version of VS Code which can cause issues if you've been holding back updating VS Code itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the VSCode itself rather than jupyter or python installation. On the actual VSCode GitHub repo, few issues are still open, apparently not fixed yet. What seems to be working though, is, to try killing all VSCode processes and trying again.

```
ps aux | grep -i vscode | less
pkill -f vscode
```

Comment: The issue lied in the company policies, forcing me to open VSCode as admin. This resulted in limited acces to certain drives. I solved this by switching companies witch better security policies for developers *LOL*